# Postgresql to Hsql

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I have this postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE News (
    tags        text[](10),
    contract    varchar(40),
    ...others
);
```

I need to get all the distinct tags for a given contract. I found the postgresql request which works well:

```
SELECT array_agg(acc)
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT unnest(tags::text[])
       FROM my_schema.news
       WHERE contract = 'acontract'
     ) AS dt(acc);
```

As I am using spring data jpa, I try to convert this request into an HSQL request but I can't make it work. Any idea on what the conversion could be?

Comment: In HSQLDB, Use "SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE"   (or the equivalent URL property sql.syntax_pgs=true) to enable the PostgreSQL's non-standard features. References to SERIAL, BIGSERIAL, TEXT and UUID data types, as well as sequence functions, are translated into HyperSQL equivalents.  Note that HSQLDB does support array types, however PostgreSQL's implementation of arrays differs from the SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE` you need to reference the arrays according to the SQL standard.

```
CREATE TABLE News (tags text array[10], contract varchar(40))
```

Then

```
select array_agg(acc) from (
   select distinct acc from news, unnest(tags) un(acc)
   WHERE contract = 'acontract'
)
```